# I would like to add a few more options to the General Options Page

Tags: wordpress

I have a few  "Global" options i would like to add to the default Wordpress  **Options page at wp-admin/options-general.php**. In other words, i would like to extend the Wordpress Options page. I know I could create an options page, but i feel that'd be an overkill for 3 options only.

I checked https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_section but for some reason i keep getting a fatal error message that the  function **add_settings_section** does not exist.

Any pointers in the right  direction please?!

Comment: Are you doing your add_settings_section in functions.php?

Comment: Yea. i have opted to create an actual "options page". There doesn't seem to be enough  documentation about this one!

Comment: I thought maybe you were calling it early, but seems like anywhere in functions.php should work.  You could try calling it on an action like init.   Look at Redux plugin.  It makes options pages super easy.